# How to split a column with multiple paterns and select specific to new columns in R

Tags: r

i have a df with `df$feature` like this :

```
head(df1)
      variant chr position source       type
1: rs10738606   9 22088090 HAVANA       gene
2: rs10738606   9 22088090 HAVANA transcript
3: rs10738606   9 22088090 HAVANA transcript
4: rs10738606   9 22088090 HAVANA transcript
5: rs10738606   9 22088090 HAVANA transcript
6: rs10738606   9 22088090 HAVANA transcript
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

feature
1: gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; tag ncRNA_host; tag overlapping_locus; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7;
2: gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; transcript_id ENST00000585267.5; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; transcript_type lncRNA; transcript_name CDKN2B-AS1-217; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; tag basic; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000445870.1;

dput(head(df1$feature))
c("gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; tag ncRNA_host; tag overlapping_locus; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; transcript_id ENST00000585267.5; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; transcript_type lncRNA; transcript_name CDKN2B-AS1-217; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; tag basic; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000445870.1;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; transcript_id ENST00000580576.6; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; transcript_type lncRNA; transcript_name CDKN2B-AS1-208; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; tag basic; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000445871.2;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; transcript_id ENST00000428597.6; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; transcript_type lncRNA; transcript_name CDKN2B-AS1-203; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; tag basic; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000334290.2;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; transcript_id ENST00000577551.5; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; transcript_type lncRNA; transcript_name CDKN2B-AS1-206; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000445875.1;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000240498.9; transcript_id ENST00000581051.5; gene_type lncRNA; gene_name CDKN2B-AS1; transcript_type lncRNA; transcript_name CDKN2B-AS1-209; level 2; transcript_support_level 1; hgnc_id HGNC:34341; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000019689.7; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000445877.1;"
)
```

I would like to separate this column into multiple columns and subset like this(the first row for example):

```
variant    chr position source  type gene_id         gene_type gene_name
rs10738606  9  22088090 HAVANA  gene ENSG00000240498.9  lncRNA CDKN2B-AS1
```

Do you know how to do it in R or Python ?

Comment: can you share `dput(head(df$feature))` ?

Comment: Yes sure i modified the question in  order to fit

Answer (score 1):

in Base R consider doing:

```
read.dcf(textConnection(gsub(" ", ":", gsub("; *", "\n", feature))),
       fields = c('gene_id', 'gene_type', 'gene_name'))

     gene_id             gene_type gene_name   
[1,] "ENSG00000240498.9" "lncRNA"  "CDKN2B-AS1"
[2,] "ENSG00000240498.9" "lncRNA"  "CDKN2B-AS1"
[3,] "ENSG00000240498.9" "lncRNA"  "CDKN2B-AS1"
[4,] "ENSG00000240498.9" "lncRNA"  "CDKN2B-AS1"
[5,] "ENSG00000240498.9" "lncRNA"  "CDKN2B-AS1"
[6,] "ENSG00000240498.9" "lncRNA"  "CDKN2B-AS1"
```

---

Notice that instead of `fields` you could use `all = TRUE` and it will give you all the fields in your strings

Comment: How to modify the above answer to split a similar row : `ID=MIMAT0027618;Alias=MIMAT0027618;Name=hsa-miR-6859-5p;Derives_from=MI0022705`

Comment: i modified the code `feature_split <- read.dcf(textConnection(gsub("=", ":", gsub(";", "\n", feature))), fields = c('ID', 'Alias', 'Name'))`  but it returns only one entry the last one and not for every row

Comment: @DimitrisZisis forvthe code to work, you must contain a valid dcf file. Check whether your dcf file is valid using cat function before you read it

Comment: my file 'feature' is valid and contains 12 lines like that :     `dput(head(df1$feature))
c("ID=MI0006444;Alias=MI0006444;Name=hsa-mir-1307", "ID=MI0017423;Alias=MI0017423;Name=hsa-mir-4779", 
"ID=MI0017263;Alias=MI0017263;Name=hsa-mir-4636", "ID=MI0016592;Alias=MI0016592;Name=hsa-mir-3936", 
"ID=MI0018176;Alias=MI0018176;Name=hsa-mir-5197", "ID=MI0016879;Alias=MI0016879;Name=hsa-mir-4513"`

Comment: What i made in the feature_split works only for one line and not for all

Comment: I see what is happening. You need an extra breakline between the lines. use `paste(gsub("=", ":", gsub(";", "\n", feature)), collapse = "\n\n")`

Comment: @DimitrisZisis the full code will be `read.dcf(textConnection(paste(gsub("=", ":", gsub(";", "\n", feature)), collapse = "\n\n")), fields = c('ID', 'Alias', 'Name'))`